# What is the most efficient way to perform math on a set of selected rows in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe of the following format:

```
Location| X | Y
----------------
A1      | 1 | 2
A1      | 2 | 3
A2      | 1 | 1
A2      | 2 | 3
etc...many locations...many values
```

I want to get the first derivative for all values in one location, and attach it to the original dataframe as X1.

```
Location| X | Y | X'
--------------------
A1      | 1 | 2 |
A1      | 2 | 3 |
A2      | 1 | 1 |
A2      | 2 | 3 |
etc...many locations...many values
```

What is the most efficient/elegant way of doing this. I have an approach that looks like this:

1.) Get all unique locations.

2.) Iterate through all locations to get only rows that match locations in a loop.

```
 grad_dict = {}
 for location in locations:
     selected_rows = df.query('{0} == "{1}")
     temp_df = np.gradient(selected_rows['X'])
     grad_dict[location] = temp_df
```

3.) Concatenate all dictionaries together kind of like this:

```
result = pd.concat([grad_dict[location] for location in locations])
```

Note: There might be some minor issues with this code, like I am not really adding this value to the Dataframe currently. But the wider point is my question below.

**My question:** Is this the most elegant/efficient way of doing so? Is there a more elegant/faster way of doing so? When there are many locations, this operation can sometimes take a few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should be able to perform a `groupby` and use `transform`:

```
df["X'"] = df.groupby('Location')['X'].transform(np.gradient)
```

In general, if you want to perform the same operation on multiple subsections of a DataFrame, `groupby` is the way to go.

The resulting output:

```
  Location  X  Y  X'
0       A1  1  2   1
1       A1  2  3   1
2       A2  1  1   1
3       A2  2  3   1
```

**Edit**

If you want to supply additional arguments to `np.gradient`, you can supply them as arguments to `transform`.  For example:

```
df["X'"] = df.groupby('Location')['X'].transform(np.gradient, 0.5, edge_order=2)
```

If you need to do something more complex, you could instead write a lambda function to specify what you want to do, or define a custom function separately and pass it to `transform`.  You should use the method above if it's possible to do so though, as creating a lambda will be slightly slower:

```
df["X'"] = df.groupby('Location')['X'].transform(lambda x: np.gradient(x, 0.5, edge_order=2))
```

Comment: Holy cow that's fast! The answer came almost instantaneously! I mean that for both on how fast the question was answered as well as how fast the code executes! Just a follow-up question: I am having difficulties putting in arguments into the gradient function. For example, if I want the step change to be 0.5 instead of 1 (default) or if I want to set edge_order=1...how would I do that?

Comment: Just to answer my own question: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html

Comment: Edited to address your comments (which it looks like you figured out already), so future readers have a self-contained answer.